# How can I declare and initialise a static int in c++ function?

Tags: c++, static

Can you help me ? I am fed up with this static int var .... Here is my function.  I want that its values **static int ban_ve** be 0 in the first function acces
and i want that the compteur increment it each time the prog acces to the methode, that to detect if programm accessed two time to the procedure .

```
void iCol::attCalc() //juste une fois cpt test
{
  static int ban_ve;  // how can I initialize it to 0 and only the first 
  if (ban_ve>0)
  {
    printf(" hello tu es dedans ....\n");
    _getch();
    exit(0);
  }
    attConD = OdemoConInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)) ;
    carConD = attConD % 16;  //  couleur de caractere par modulo carConD
    bckConD = attConD - carConD;
    bckConCH = bckConD / 16;  //  car hexa couleur de fond  (ex F)
    printf("attcalc attConD %d carConD %d bckConD %d bckConCH %d \n",attConD, carConD ,bckConD ,bckConCH );
    ban_ve++;
}
```

Comment: "how can I initialize it to 0 and only the first?": Simply by `static int ban_ve = 0;`

Comment: `static int ban_ve = 0;` didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just write `static int ban_ve = 0;`

It's guaranteed that `ban_ve` will be initialized only once.

6.7$4 Declaration statement [stmt.dcl]:

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant
>   initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage
>   duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first
>   entered. An implementation is permitted to perform early
>   initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread
>   storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is
>   permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread
>   storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable
>   is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration;
>   such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its
>   initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception,
>   the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next
>   time control enters the declaration. If control enters the declaration
>   concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent
>   execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.93 If
>   control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is
>   being initialized, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `static int ban_ve` as a global variable and increment it everytime function is called :

```
static int ban_ve = 0;
void iCol::attCalc()
{
    ban_ve++;
    //rest of code
}
```